# SQL Server 2008 : selecting one record, group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table

```
#tblA (mem_id int, type varchar(20), address1 varchar(20),group_id int)

insert into #tblA (mem_id, type, address1,group_id)
values (1,'self','abc St',1),
       (2,'Child','abc St',1),
       (3,'Child','xyz st',1),
       (4,'spouse','pqr st',1),
       (5,'Child','abc St',1),
       (6,'Child','xyz st',1),

       (7,'self','mno st',2),
       (8,'Child','def St',2),
       (9,'Child','def st',2),
```

I want to select only child and spouse who live on different address. Also if two people from group live at the different address from self, then I need just one person.

This is the expected result:

```
   (3, 'Child', 'xyz st', 1),
   (4, 'spouse', 'pqr st', 1),
   (8, 'Child', 'def St', 2),
```

eliminating id2 and id5 because its address is same as id1. eliminating id6 because we already get id3 in result. eliminating id7 because it is self and id9 because we already got id8 for same address.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is rather complicated.  The following query takes the approach of first getting all candidate "spouse" and "child" records.  It then chooses one of them using `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group_id, type order by mem_id) as seqnum
      from tbla a
      where a.type <> 'self' and
            a.address1 <> (select address1
                           from tbla a2
                           where a2.group_id = a.group_id and
                                 a2.type = 'self'
                          )
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can see it work at this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed3c8/9).